# XPath 1.0 to find a sibling of an attribute node whose name is based on the attribute, but has a suffix

Tags: xpath

Given the following Xml:

```
<Root><Foo Bar="" Bar_Baz="12" /></Root>
```

Is there an XPath statement (using version 1.0 functions only) that can return `Root/Foo/@Bar` where there exists some sibling attribute starting with `Bar` (determined by context), and ending in `_Baz`, where that node has the value 12?

`Bar` should be anonymous - the XPath shouldn't care what it's called - but whatever it is called, if it is returned or not should be determined by whether X_Baz exists, and has the value of 12.

I was looking into something like:

```
//@*[sibling::@*[concat(local-name(), '_Baz') = '12']
```

But fairly obviously, this would just compare the text `Bar_Baz` to `12`, not the value of that sibling attribute.

I'm making use of this using the .Net `XmlDocument` class, meaning I'm limited to Microsoft's XPath 1.0 implementation, so please don't make use of subsequent versions of the spec!

EDIT: Per the comment requesting a more diverse set of examples, see below:

```
<Root>
  <Item Foo="" Foo_Baz="12">Yes - @Foo_Baz is 12, and @Foo exists</Item>
  <Item Bar="" Bar_Baz="12">Yes - @Bar_Baz is 12, and @Bar exists</Item>
  <Item Foo="" Foo_Baz="1">No - Foo_Baz != 12<Item>
  <Item Baz="" Foo_Baz="12">No - No @Foo to return</Item>
  <Item Foo_Baz="12">No - No @Foo to return</Item>
  <Item Foo="" Foo_Haz="12">No - No @Foo_Baz node to check the value of</Item>
</Root>
```

Edit 2:
Looking at the first couple of answers proposed, I think there is something I haven't been clear on: the names, Foo or Bar, are unknown. The only things that *are* known are:

- There are one or more attributes with a suffix `_Baz` that has the value `12`
- They may have siblings whose entire name is whatever came before the suffice
- If they do, then *that sibling* is the node I want to match, *provided* the `_Baz` attribute has the value of `12`

Comment: Can you edit your question with a 3 or 4 more elements some of which meet and some fail your condition? It's not exactly clear.

Comment: And you are looking to do this in a single XPath expression? No chance of selecting values in one and using the value in a second XPath?

Comment: I am. My current implementation selects all attributes ending in `_Baz` using `susbtring-after(local-name(),'_')` and then executes `SelectSingleNode` on each of those. I'm concerned that that is potentially computationally more expensive than doing the action inline. I'm not particularly familiar with how XPath gets handled - whether it's compiled or parsed, for instance - so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option :

```
//item[substring-after(local-name(./@*[last()]),"_")="baz" and ./@*[last()]="12"][local-name(./@*[1])=substring-before(local-name(./@*[last()]),"_")]
```

Shortest form :

```
//item[@foo or @bar][@bar_baz="12" or @foo_baz="12"]
```

**EDIT :** Massive and horrible XPath here, but it should work. It supports up to 5 attributes per item and regardless the position of these attributes inside each item tag.

```
//item[contains(local-name(@*[1]),"_baz") and @*[1]=12][local-name(@*[1])=substring-before(local-name(@*[1]),"_")]|//item[contains(local-name(@*[1]),"_baz") and @*[1]=12][local-name(@*[3])=substring-before(local-name(@*[1]),"_")]|//item[contains(local-name(@*[1]),"_baz") and @*[1]=12][local-name(@*[4])=substring-before(local-name(@*[1]),"_")]|//item[contains(local-name(@*[1]),"_baz") and @*[1]=12][local-name(@*[5])=substring-before(local-name(@*[1]),"_")]|//item[contains(local-name(@*[2]),"_baz") and @*[2]=12][local-name(@*[1])=substring-before(local-name(@*[2]),"_")]|//item[contains(local-name(@*[2]),"_baz") and @*[2]=12][local-name(@*[3])=substring-before(local-name(@*[2]),"_")]|//item[contains(local-name(@*[2]),"_baz") and @*[2]=12][local-name(@*[4])=substring-before(local-name(@*[2]),"_")]|//item[contains(local-name(@*[2]),"_baz") and @*[2]=12][local-name(@*[5])=substring-before(local-name(@*[2]),"_")]|//item[contains(local-name(@*[3]),"_baz") and @*[3]=12][local-name(@*[1])=substring-before(local-name(@*[3]),"_")]|//item[contains(local-name(@*[3]),"_baz") and @*[3]=12][local-name(@*[3])=substring-before(local-name(@*[3]),"_")]|//item[contains(local-name(@*[3]),"_baz") and @*[3]=12][local-name(@*[4])=substring-before(local-name(@*[3]),"_")]|//item[contains(local-name(@*[3]),"_baz") and @*[3]=12][local-name(@*[5])=substring-before(local-name(@*[3]),"_")]|//item[contains(local-name(@*[4]),"_baz") and @*[4]=12][local-name(@*[1])=substring-before(local-name(@*[4]),"_")]|//item[contains(local-name(@*[4]),"_baz") and @*[4]=12][local-name(@*[3])=substring-before(local-name(@*[4]),"_")]|//item[contains(local-name(@*[4]),"_baz") and @*[4]=12][local-name(@*[4])=substring-before(local-name(@*[4]),"_")]|//item[contains(local-name(@*[4]),"_baz") and @*[4]=12][local-name(@*[5])=substring-before(local-name(@*[4]),"_")]|//item[contains(local-name(@*[5]),"_baz") and @*[5]=12][local-name(@*[1])=substring-before(local-name(@*[5]),"_")]|//item[contains(local-name(@*[5]),"_baz") and @*[5]=12][local-name(@*[3])=substring-before(local-name(@*[5]),"_")]|//item[contains(local-name(@*[5]),"_baz") and @*[5]=12][local-name(@*[4])=substring-before(local-name(@*[5]),"_")]|//item[contains(local-name(@*[5]),"_baz") and @*[5]=12][local-name(@*[5])=substring-before(local-name(@*[5]),"_")]
```

Working sample (4 nodes selected) :

[image: XPath Horror]

Comment: This got me a LOT closer to what I needed - looks like the correct XPath is `//*[substring-after(local-name(./@*[last()]),'_')='Bar' and ./@*[last()]='Y']/@*[substring-before(local-name(../@*[last()]),'_')=local-name()]`. That said I must admit I don't completely understand when `last()` changes - so need to look that up!

Comment: ... Although actually, unfortunately, it looks like last() isn't the previously matched node, but the last item in the list. That means that this fails for `<Root><Foo Bar_Baz="Y" Bar="X" /></Root>`

Comment: Wow, that's a long one! I'll give it a try and see how it compares to the non-XPath approach

Answer (score 0):

Strictly in terms of xpath, this expression

```
//Item[attribute::*[contains(local-name(), '_Baz')]='12'][attribute::*[local-name()='Foo'] | attribute::*[local-name()='Bar']]
```

should get you your desired output.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work without knowing ahead of time what attributes may have a `_Baz` suffix. I'd be looking for an XPath that would also work for *any* combination of `X` and `X_Baz` where X can be any valid attribute name.

Comment: @tobriand - I don't understand you, I'm afraid. Can you edit the question with more item examples where the expression would either fail to select the right item or select the wrong item?

Comment: The problem isn't that the expression would select incorrect nodes - it's the I am dealing with largely unknown input. As such, _without changing the xpath_ I would want to handle the pairs (`Bar`, `Bar_Baz`), ('Microsoft', 'Microsoft_Baz'), ('Coffee', 'Coffee_Baz') etc., where both could be on *any* element, in any order.

Comment: @tobriand - OK, I think I get it now; let me think about it. Fair warning, if it works, it's going to be long and convoluted in xpath 1.0...

Comment: @tobriand Are the `X` and `X_baz` attributes always the first and second attributes, respectively, of `Item`?

Comment: Nope. They are just shared on the same element. It's also tricky to mandate that the two attributes have a positional relationship to eachother (such as the `X_Baz` attribute always following the `X` one), though that might be possible to ensure elsewhere. Basic issue is attributes aren't really meant for object-style data!